# Extend OAuth2 Authorization Server with OpenID Connect

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to extend my home made OAuth2 Authorization Server with the OpenID Connect. At the moment, the Server works fine and successfully issues an access token.

What I need is that the token endpoint returns an `id_token` along with the `access_token`.

The Authorization Server is a Spring boot (2.5) app, which implements the authorization code flow using following oauth dependencies.

```
spring-security-oauth2
spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
spring-security-jwt
spring-security-oauth2-jose
```

Is there some standard way to configure an OAuth2 Spring Server so it provides the OpenID Connect features?

Thanks in advance for an example code and/or useful documenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring team are working on a new OAuth server, that provides OIDC capability. It's still very early days, but it is useable.

See here for the code, that includes a set of samples:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server